# Azure ADF : Failed to decrypt sub-resource 'None' payload on cloud with error: Failed to decrypt sub-resource payload

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a cloud training provider subscription which provides an Azure sandbox for 4 hours. In this sandbox I don’t have access to create a resource group. A pre-built resource group is created and I am only allowed to create resources within that resource group. Once this window is over all the resources present within the resource groups are deleted. Next time when I start an Azure sand box then a new resource group is created and I create the resources again to resume my learning process.

The resources which I am using are:-
•   Azure Data factory
•   Blob Storage
•   Azure data lake storage gen2

I am using my personal github account as code repository.

As we are all aware of the fact that ADF uses two branches to manage the code. One is the collaboration branch and the other is the publish branch. As I am the only developer my collaboration branch is the main and publish branch is adf_publish. On the first 4 hour window I create the resources as mentioned above and use my personal github account as code repository. I develop a pipeline in ADF and  commit it to my collaboration branch (i.e. main) and publish it .As soon as I publish the code, then the code gets published to ADF and ARM templates are created and pushed to github adf_publish branch . Now as the first 4 hour window is over then my subscription is deleted which results to deletion of all my resources. But my codebase is still present in my personal github repository.

Now comes the second 4 hour window. I have a new resource group and I re-create all the resources as mentioned above. Once ADF is created I go to Monitor tab and click on ARM template. Please find the below screenshot.

[image]

Post that I went to “Import ARM template” option and clicked on “Import on Azure portal”.

[image]

By clicking on the above button it opens up an editor which looks like below

[image]

Now I navigate to my personal github account and copy the contents of  a file (i.e. ARMTemplateForFactory.json) present in adf_publish branch and paste it to the above editor.

[image]

After clicking on save ADF asks me for connection string for all the linked services which I have used. I put them and then clicked on Review+Create. It takes some time and then all my old codebase that I developed in first 4 hour window is restored . I execute the ADF pipeline and it works as expected.

But when I hookup my ADF instance with my private git repository (i.e. same github repo which I used to develop in first 4 hour window) and execute the pipeline then I get the below errors

```
"properties": { "description": "ls_blbstrgxxxxx", "annotations": [], "type": "AzureBlobStorage", "typeProperties": { "connectionString": "********************", "encryptedCredential": "********************" } }, "name": "ls_blbstrgxxxx" } and error is: Cloud stored credentials cannot be found with retry, please check whether related resource had been deleted before. Value is: { "Version": "2017-11-30", "ProtectionMode": "Key", "SecretContentType": "Plaintext", "CredentialId": "DATAFACTORY@557664FD-2438-41D3-89C5-55745793C95D_2e7ce169-147d-4627-ac84-9ae31b270aac" }, type is Plaintext and credentialId is DATAFACTORY@557664FD-2438-41D3-89C5-55745793C95D_2e7ce169-147d-4627-ac84-9ae31b270aac.., status code: BadRequest.
```

[image]

The code which is present in “Publish” mode of ADF works fine but unfortunately code which is present in main branch of my private github throws me the above error. Due to this error I am unable to develop ADF pipelines across different Azure sandbox subscriptions.

Please help me to resolve the above issue if anyone has faced.

Comment: Hi. I'm facing the same problem as you. Did you ever find a solution? If you did, could you share it here as an answer, please?